# Reusing minitest integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have three pages in Rails that all display the same header, and hence would require the exact same integration tests.

Instead of repeating myself and writing separate tests that look almost exactly the same, what's the best approach here? I've tried putting the shared assertions into a module but haven't been successful getting it to load into each test scenario.

UNDRY:

```
class IntegrationTest
  describe "page one" do

    before { visit page_one_path }

    it "should have a home page link" do
      page.find_link "Home"
    end
  end

  describe "page two" do

    before { visit page_two_path }

    it "should have a home page link" do
      page.find_link "Home"
    end
  end

  describe "page three" do

    before { visit page_three_path }

    it "should have a home page link" do
      page.find_link "Home"
    end
  end
end
```

Failed attempt at drying it out...

Module:

```
/lib/tests/shared_test.rb

module SharedTest

  def test_header
    it "should have a home page link" do
      page.find_link "Home"
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```
class IntegrationTest
  include SharedTest

  describe "page one" do
    before { visit page_one_path }
    test_header
  end

  describe "page two" do
    before { visit page_two_path }
    test_header        
  end

  describe "page three" do
    before { visit page_three_path }
    test_header
  end
end
```

I haven't quite figured out how to write modules yet so it's no surprise that this doesn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: First, I'm not sure it's necessary to test this for every single controller action unless you're constantly changing layouts (and even then, there are probably easier ways to test this). For a more general answer to the question of using shared examples in MiniTest,  the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/spec/rdoc/MiniTest/Spec.html) recommend: "If you do want inheritence, use minitest/unit. You can mix and match between assertions and expectations as much as you want."

Answer (score 4):

The way to share tests between different `describe` blocks when using Minitest's spec DSL is to include the module in each `describe` block you want those tests to run in.

```
module SharedTest
  def test_header
    assert_link "Home"
  end
end

class IntegrationTest < ActiveDispatch::IntegrationTest
  describe "page one" do
    include SharedTest
    before { visit page_one_path }
  end

  describe "page two" do
    include SharedTest
    before { visit page_two_path }
  end

  describe "page three" do
    include SharedTest
    before { visit page_three_path }
  end
end
```

One of the ways the Minitest's Test API is different than Minitest Spec DSL is in how they behave when being inherited. Consider the following:

```
class PageOneTest < ActiveDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    visit page_one_path
  end

  def test_header
    assert_link "Home"
  end
end

class PageTwoTest < PageOneTest
  def setup
    visit page_two_path
  end
end

class PageThreeTest < PageOneTest
  def setup
    visit page_three_path
  end
end
```

The PageTwoTest and PageThreeTest test classes inherit from PageOneTest, and because of that they all have the `test_header` method. Minitest will run all three tests. But, when implemented with the spec DSL the `test_header` method is not inherited.

```
class PageOneTest < ActiveDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    visit page_one_path
  end

  def test_header
    assert_link "Home"
  end

  describe "page two" do
    before { visit page_two_path }
  end

  describe "page three" do
    before { visit page_three_path }
  end
end
```

In this case, only one test is run. The test class created by `describe "page two"` will inherit from PageOneTest, but will have all of the test methods removed. Why? Because Minitest's spec DSL is based on RSpec, and this is the way that RSpec works. Minitest goes out of its way to nuke the test methods that are inherited when using the spec DSL. So the only way to share *tests* while using the spec DSL is to include the module in each `describe` block you want them to be in. All other non-*test* methods, including the `before` and `after` hooks, and the `let` accessors, will be inherited

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clean way to reuse tests when using MiniTest's spec DSL - define the tests inside a function and call that function where you want to include your tests.

Example:

```
def include_shared_header_tests
  it "should be longer than 5 characters" do
    assert subject.length > 5
  end

  it "should have at least one capital letter" do
    assert /[A-Z]/ =~ subject
  end
end

# This block will pass
describe "A good header" end
  subject { "I'm a great header!" }

  include_shared_header_tests
end

# This block will fail
describe "A bad header" end
  subject { "bad" }

  include_shared_header_tests
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue to use the Spec style in the module, you can use the `Module::included` hook.

```
module SharedTests
  def self.included spec
    spec.class_eval do

      # Your shared code here...

      let(:foo) { 'foo' }

      describe '#foo' do
        it { foo.must_equal 'foo' }
      end

    end
  end
end

class MyTest < Minitest::Spec
  include SharedTests
end

class MyOtherTest < Minitest::Spec
  include SharedTests
end

# It also works in nested describe blocks.
class YetAnotherTest < Minitest::Spec
  describe 'something' do
    describe 'when it acts some way' do
      include SharedTests
    end
  end
end
```

Another approach to repetitive tests is iteration.

```
class IntegrationTest < Minitest::Spec
  {
    'page one'   => :page_one_path,
    'page two'   => :page_two_path,
    'page three' => :page_three_path,
  }.each do |title, path|
    describe title do
      before { visit send(path) }

      it 'should have a home page link' do
        page.find_link 'Home'
      end
    end
  end
end
```